`async-shell-command: Wrong type argument: sequencep, #<buffer *scratch*>`
This is not a question about switching to the scratch buffer but to understand why the error is produced and to correct the function.
By running the following command from command line, I can switch to a visible scratch buffer (if any), or to create a new frame containing the scratch buffer.
emacsclientw -na runemacs -e "(progn (if (get-buffer-window \"*scratch*\" 'visible) (switch-to-buffer \"*scratch*\") (switch-to-buffer-other-frame \"*scratch*\")))"
Trying to convert the above command into an elisp function within emacs I have the below function
(defun my-scratch () (interactive)
(async-shell-command (concat
"emacsclientw -na runemacs -e " ""(progn (if (get-buffer-window "*scratch*" 'visible) (switch-to-buffer "*scratch*") (switch-to-buffer-other-frame "*scratch*")))""
)))

But running the above function emacs complains that:
async-shell-command: Wrong type argument: sequencep, #<buffer *scratch*>
How to modify the function for working properly?
Edit: Following the comments, parentheses and backslashes should be escaped as well. The following code seems to solve the problem and runs without error.
(defun my-scratch () (interactive) (shell-command (concat "emacsclientw -na runemacs -e " "\"(progn (if (get-buffer-window \\\"*scratch*\\\" 'visible) (switch-to-buffer \\\"*scratch*\\\") (switch-to-buffer-other-frame \\\"*scratch*\\\")))\"" ))) 


At the very least, you need to escape any inner double quotes within a string: "This is a \"quoted string\" within a string".

You seem to think that two double quotes can be used to delimit strings and that then you don't have to escape inner double quotes (perhaps similar to triple quotes in Python?). AFAIK, that is not the case in Emacs Lisp: strings are delimited by double quotes (one double quote at the beginning and one at the end) and inner double quotes must be escaped.

@NickD Thank you. Parentheses and backslashes are should be escaped as well. The following should seems to aolve eteh proble,
(defun my-scratch () (interactive)
(shell-command (concat
"emacsclientw -na runemacs -e " ""(progn (if (get-buffer-window \"scratch\" 'visible) (switch-to-buffer \"scratch\") (switch-to-buffer-other-frame \"scratch\")))""
)))

That's unreadable - please update your question. Or provide a reasonably formatted answer.
